# Get the type of a class in a generic context

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am building a little application framework with generic repositories and business objects in ASP-NET Core 2.0.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    public Repository()
    {
        var myClass = typeof(TEntity);
        var myClassName = myClass.Name; // I would expect "Person" - but it says "IEntity" - what am I doing wrong?
    }
}

public abstract class BusinessBase<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    private Repository<IEntity> _repository { get; set; }

    public BusinessBase()
    {
        var myClass = typeof(TEntity);
        var myClassName = myClass.Name; // "Person" as expected

        this._repository = new Repository<IEntity>();
    }
}

public class BusinessPerson : BusinessBase<Person>
{
}
```

Put this code e.g. in a console application and then call

```
 var x = new BusinessPerson();
```

You will notice that I am trying to read the name of the generic TEntity in the "Repository" class. I couldn't figure out why it doesn't say "Person". Any ideas or help?

Please let's not talk about the general design of my approach here. My real program looks different but I simplified it as much as possible so you guys don't need to read 100s of lines of code.

Comment: You said `new Repository<IEntity>()`. I think you need `new Repository<TEntity>()`

Comment: No, sorry, this won't compile. :(

Comment: Because you need also to make `_repository` the same type.

Comment: And a name like `_repository` looks like a field, but you made it a property.

Comment: It doesn't say `Person` because `Repository<TEntity>` wasn't constructed with `Person`.  It was constructed with `IEntity`.

Comment: Sure, I declare `private Repository<TEntity> _repository` then it works. But my real program requires an IEntity to be passed.

Comment: And so `typeof` is correctly reporting the truth: that `Respository<IEntity>` was constructed with `IEntity`.  Where do you suppose that `Person` is coming from? In your program `Respoitory<T>` is **never constructed with Person**, so why would you expect it to report that it was?

Comment: @Eric: Well, I am probably misunderstanding the whole concept. I was hoping for the base class BusinessBase<Person> to pass a Person.

Comment: But you don't pass *anything anywhere* in this program.  I'm voting to close this as unclear what you're asking.  If you want Respository to be constructed with `Person` then construct it with `Person`. If you want it to be constructed with *the same thing that BusinessPerson was constructed with* then construct it with `TEntity`.

Comment: Suppose I wrote `class Bar<T> { List<Animal> foo = new List<Animal>(); }`  Is your theory that `Bar<Giraffe>` should somehow make `Bar<Giraffe>.foo` of type `List<Giraffe>`?  What leads you to this theory? **The code says `List<Animal>` so that's what you get**.  The fact that some completely other type happens to be constructed with some completely other type is irrelevant. The code does what it says it does. You said `Repository<IEntity>` and unsurprisingly, that's what you got, *regardless of the context*.

Comment: @Eric: I agree. I probably simplified my real program too much. Just replacing IEntity with TEntity (as Dennis already suggested in the beginning) brings up other problems in my code.  I will need to improve my sample code. What I posted here really doesn't make too much sense. So, sorry for bringing this up this way. Unfortunately I have to leave now. But I will catch up later again.

Comment: Your real code is probably running into a covariance/contravariance issue. Remember, **a list of giraffes is not a list of animals**.  You can put a tiger into a list of animals, but not into a list of giraffes; since the two types have different capabilities, they are not subtypes of each other. A repository of `Person` is not a repository of `IEntity` for the same reason: you can put a *non-person* into a repository of `IEntity`, and so they are not the same type.

Comment: Now, a list of giraffes *is* an `IEnumerable<Animal>` because `IEnumerable<T>` provides you no way to put a tiger into the sequence. **C# permits covariance and contravariance only on generic interfaces and delegates that are marked as safe for variance and constructed with reference types**.

Comment: @Eric: I am really embarrassed. Of course I know that `Bar<Giraffe>.foo` would not be of type `List<Giraffe>`. But I was mistakenly assuming that `public abstract class BusinessBase<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity`would treat the given `TEntity` as `IEntity` and somehow pass this `IEntity` in `new Repository<IEntity>`. Obviously this was kind of a ridiculous idea. This is the first time I am working seriously with generics. My real application probably isn't that well designed either. So, I guess I better go back to preschool. Thanks so much for all your help and suggestions so far!

Comment: Well there are a number of ways you *could* get that passed along. The first -- create `Repository<TEntity>` -- you've rejected. Another way would be to make `Repository` a non-generic nested class inside `BusinessBase`, so that it automatically gets the `TEntity` of its outer class.  But as you've written the code there is no relationship at all between `BusinessBase` and `Repository` aside from the fact that one creates an instance of the other.

Comment: Well, I just managed to switch to `Repository<TEntity>`. Made some changes to the rest of my code and now it compiles and `var myClass = typeof(TEntity)` returns what I expect. So, everything is fine now - and I did learn a lot about this. Totally misunderstood the meaning of generic constraints like `where TEntity : IEntity`. Thank you so much Eric (and everybody else). My bad!

Comment: Good. Now take this opportunity to ask yourself the question you should have asked in the first place: **am I abusing generics in this application**? I suspect you might be. Generics work best when there is a very clear relationship between the generic type and the type parameter. `List<Giraffe>` is a *list of giraffes*. `IComparator<string>` is *a thing that can compare strings*. `Func<Apple, bool>` is a function that takes an apple and returns a bool. I look at `BusinessBase<T>` and I have no idea what that means; I don't know what a "business base" is or what its relationship is to T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is occurring because of your declaration of _repository. You defined the type as IEntity without it being covariant. The simple resolution would be to change the definition of _repository to the following.

```
public abstract class BusinessBase<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    private Repository<TEntity> _repository { get; set; }

    public BusinessBase()
    {
        var myClass = typeof(TEntity);
        var myClassName = myClass.Name; // "Person" as expected

        this._repository = new Repository<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

If you need _repository to be IEntity, there would be a lot more changes involved. Look into Covariance https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=covariance